# REST actions on a resource

Tags: rest

Lets say I have a resource /entities/1234 
Entities is a collection and 1234 is an id of an entity. 
An entity is a database record and a bunch of files on the server. I have an action that builds an xml model and some other stuff of an entity. 
I came up with this:

POST /entities/1234/builder

**{"active" : "true"}**

But I am not sure if it is a restful way. It doesn't feel right to think of builder as a child resource of an entity. Or is it okay?

Comment: So you want to submit an command as post body? What would 'POST /entities/1234/builder' do without the '{"active" : "true"}'?

Comment: Welcome to REST. If you end up defining a standard for this, let me know because I'd be really interested in having a standard way of doing this. And, if you think this is hard, wait until you hit optimistic locking :)

Comment: @EngineerDollery The REST rules are simple, if you can't do something, mint a new resource to do it.  Yeah, I know it's often not simple.  As far as optimistic locking, that's never been easy, but at least we have 409 and conditional write requests.

Answer (score 1):

The term "builder" is a bit strange, but your approach would work without any negative side effects that I can think of.  Well, other than making cache invalidation harder, but that's likely to be the case with most approaches.

Personally, I would go for,

```
  POST /entities/1234/activator
```

and

```
  POST /entities/1234/deactivator
```

with an empty body, just so that I don't have to worry about the format of the body and parsing it.  However, it just depends how easy it is to create new resources in your web framework.

The other approach is something like,

```
  POST /EntityActivator
  Content-Type: text/uri-list

  http://example.org/entities/1234
  http://example.org/entities/1237
```

The nice advantage of this approach is that you get to do "batch" activations and deactivations.  It all depends whether your activation code is generic to all entities or whether you have entity specific activation code or not.

Comment: If I see a url on a rest api I expect it to lead to a resource, not be a simple way of invoking a remote method. If I see resource/activator then I expect to have access to the activator sub-resource. While your solution works, it pollutes the rest api with non-rest urls, and therefore makes it less intuitive and reduces your rest maturity. I agree that this isn't dreadful, but if you're trying to do rest this is not the right way to do it  -- this is simply a remote procedure call. *note: I don't know what the right way is, but I can recognise wrong when I see it :)

Comment: @EngineerDollery There is no such thing as a "rest-url".  It is a fallacy.  I defined a resource on the server and gave it the identifier `/entities/1234/activator`.  This is just as valid a resource as '/entities/1234'

Comment: @EngineerDollery When trying to identify if something is "RESTful" it is important to identify if any constraints are being violated and what are the impacts of violating those constraints.  Using a POST with a resource to make a change to related resource is a perfectly valid use of HTTP.  Just because you see a verb in a URL doesn't mean it is being used like an RPC call.

Comment: I think that we have fundamentally different views on this, hence our discussion. Like I said in my answer, there are no standards so there is no right or wrong. Given that, the answer to this question is opinion based, it should probably be closed on that basis, but I think it's such a good question and useful discussion that I don't have the heart to vote to close it. However, it may not meet the SO standards, and you have more rep than me so probably know better, what do you think?

Comment: @EngineerDollery The constraints of REST are documented here http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm and here http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven I believe the question is valid and should remain.  You may feel it is a matter of opinion, but I'm quite sure if you search SO for the distinction between REST and RPC I've probably answered it a few times before. http://stackoverflow.com/tags/rest/topusers

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your solution is ok, but there is no standard way to do this in REST so who knows.

I'd recommend sending the command via a custom header on the POST. This simplifies routing in your controller (at least it simplifies it in Spring), and doesn't infect your url with unbookmarkable cache-busting random data, and doesn't infect your objects with unparsable attributes that shouldn't be part of the object in the first place.

I wrote about [this on my blog](http://engineerdollery.com/2013/12/19/rest-non-crud/), if you're interested.

### Edit:

It could be argued that what you're ultimately trying to do with the type of command in your question is change the state of a resource, and therefore you should just update the object's state value on the client then post the modified object back, letting the server work out how to handle the change. But this doesn't really apply to commands like **Print**.

Comment: So, basically I POST to /entities/1234 an empty body with a custom header?

Comment: Putting custom commands in the header would be the least obvious thing you could do -- although it does eliminate some problems.

Comment: what do you mean by 'least obvious'? I don't think I know what you mean by 'obvious'.

Comment: @user1745356 -- yeah, that's my approach. This stuff isn't really well understood yet and there are trade-offs will all approaches right now, but that's the best I could come up with when I had similar problems.

Comment: If you are POSTing to the resource, why would sending a command in the body ''infect" your object?  You shouldn't need to send your object at all.

Comment: @DarrelMiller -- it's about routing the request on the server side. If you don't have some way of routing to a command handler, rather than the normal post handlers, then a lot of implementations will try to bind the body of the post to a specific object type, and upon failing that will return an error. Spring, JAX-RS, Backbone, and many other frameworks do exactly this. You'd have to do something other than send the command in the body to allow these frameworks to realise that you haven't actually posted the resource that you've referenced in the URL.

Comment: You could then use a different Request Method, like PUT or PATCH.

Comment: @EngineerDollery Ahh, I see.  It's a real shame when framework implementation mechanisms that are designed to make life easier, actually end up constraining the HTTP interface.